# Powershell - Different method of including code?

Tags: powershell, scripting, include

I have 3x scripts:

- C:\Powershell\Test1.ps1:

  `WRITE-HOST "My Name is" $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name
  . "C:\Powershell\Test2.ps1"`
- C:\Powershell\Test2.ps1:

  `WRITE-HOST "My Name is" $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name
  . "C:\Powershell\Test3.ps1"`
- C:\Powershell\Test3.ps1:

  `WRITE-HOST "My Name is" $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name`

This is the output: 

    `PS C:\Powershell> .\Test1.ps1
    My Name is Test1.ps1
    My Name is Test2.ps1
    My Name is Test3.ps1`

I would like Test1.ps1 to INCLUDE the code within itself instead of calling them as scripts inside itself.

If possible, this is the sort of output I'd like:

    `PS C:\Powershell> .\Test1.ps1
    My Name is Test1.ps1
    My Name is Test1.ps1
    My Name is Test1.ps1`

Is this possible? The original Test1 script is called, so this should the name of the script throughout, regardless of what it then calls afterwards?

Comment: You basically want that `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name` contains a different script file then the file itself? Why do you want to do that?

Comment: `$MyInvocation` will not be consistent across multiple files. Maybe you can use another script to concatenate `Test1.ps1`, `Test2.ps1` and `Test3.ps1` ? They would all be running in the same context then.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Get-Content cmdlet I guess. Try something like this:

```
WRITE-HOST "My Name is $($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name) `n`n $(Get-Content $($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name))"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following to read the contents of your scripts:

```
foreach ($File in (Get-Item -Path C:\PowerShell\* -Filter '*.ps1' | Select -ExpandProperty FullName))
{
    Write-Output "File: $File"
    Get-Content "$File"
}
```

The output would look like this:

```
PS C:\> foreach ($File in (Get-Item -Path C:\PowerShell\* -Filter '*.ps1' | Select -ExpandProperty FullName))
{
    Write-Output "File: $File"
    Get-Content "$File"
}
File: C:\PowerShell\test.ps1
test1 contents
File: C:\PowerShell\test2.ps1
test2 contents
File: C:\PowerShell\test3.ps1
test3 contents
```